# Dependency of Internal Energy on Volume and Entropy

Tags: thermodynamics

How do we establish the fact that internal energy depends on entropy and volume? Does it not depend on the temperature?

Regards,
Armaan

Answer (score 0):

Your question is badly defined, as you didn't specify which sort of system you were talking about. However, it's very likely a single-phase pure system. Let's assume that.

First, the [phase rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phase_rule), or Gibbs rule, tells you that this system has two degrees of freedom, typically to be chosen among state parameters. Therefore $U$ can be built as a function of two variables. Which ones?

Second, internal energy's thermodynamic identity is:
$$dU=-P\,dV+T\,dS$$

Remember the general expression for the exact differential of a function $f$ depending on two variables $x$ and $y$:
$$df=\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}\,dx+\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}\,dy$$
So you can deduce that $U$ is identified as a function of $V$ and $S$.

Of course, after that you're still free to use a state equation to make a change of variable and replace $V$ or $S$ with temperature, but that's the starting point.